# Generator of natural numbers which returns the smallest number which was returned already but didn't freed yet

Tags: algorithm, performance, collections

I am looking for a known algorithm for the following task:

1. I need an object `X` which provides me with two methods:

   - `take()` which returns the smallest natural number which is not taken, i.e. sequential calls of this method would return `1`, `2`, `3` and so on.
   - `free(n)` which marks `n` as not taken if it was taken already or throws exception if it wasn't or was freed after that.

Example:

```
take = 1
take = 2
take = 3
free(2)
take = 2
take = 4
free(3)
free(2)
free(1)
take = 1
take = 2
take = 3
take = 5
free(6) : exception
```

I've invented bit-set-b-tree (not sure how to call it correctly) where leaves contain the actual bit set for all taken numbers while other nodes group leaves for search purposes. Every non-leaf node has 32 children, so the memory overhead is 1/31 of bit for every bit in the leaf bitset.

The actual search of the 'hole' in the node (both leaf and non-leaf) is done as bit-operations-based binary search which takes `log2(32) = 5` operations, while walk through nodes from root to leaves takes `log32(L)` where `L` is last number which is in 'taken' state.

Therefore, both operations cost `5*log32(L)` and it takes about `1.032*L` bits to store that structure in memory. In the worst case, L couldn't be bigger than maximal number of taken numbers at the same time. It could to not decrease even if all numbers are freed except one, but if there never were more than 10 numbers taken at the moment, L will be less or equal to ten.

What do you think about my reinvention of the wheel?

The reason why I need that structure is a very specific id generation but maybe there could be other applyings? This is a bonus question :)

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a sorted list for the freed numbers.

Let n denote the maximum number returned by the take() function. 
Every time the free(d) has been called, first search for d in the sorted list and throw exception if necessary! otherwise, insert d into the sorted list. The whole operation has a cost of O(log n).

Now, every time the the take() function has been called, simply return the minimum number in it and delete-min with cost O(1). If the sorted list was empty, increment n and return it.

Note that their is no memory overhead in this approach :)

Comment: Imagine that `take` was called `100,000` times and `free` was called for every odd (or even) taken number. After that, the list of freed numbers would be `50,000*bits_in(int)` bits, which is `16*L` bits, so you are not correct when you say that there is no memory overhead.

Comment: That special case is absolutely right. On the other hand if the number of freed numbers is less than L/32, the list requires less memory. For example if after taking 100,000 numbers, only 100 of them are freed, the list requires 3,200 bits while the tree requires more than 100,000 bits.

Comment: @xpda pointed me that in the case when there are few freed nodes, I can get rid of leaves. It's not possible to do that with my implementation but maybe I can use your idea. Maybe it worth to store freed nodes in the list until their amount become big enough and build tree at that moment. P.S. upvoted to counterbalance someone's downvote :)

Comment: @Grief Just another note (it may seem over thinking though!): the so called list can be stored as a list of lists. Each list consisting of 16 bit numbers along with a 16-bit index. This structure reduces the storage size to nearly half of the original case. Just thinking loudly. Thanks for the vote by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty efficient.

Every non-leaf node will have, on average, less than 32 children. 32 is correct maximum for the binary search time of the leaves, but maybe some smaller number d should be used for the base in 5*log<sub>d</sub>(L), either the average or minimum density.

Comment: Yes, 32 is not hard-coded but I prefer to keep it consistent with processor's register size (32 or 64)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point. I store all nodes, even 'full' and 'empty' to avoid pointers at all. I store 'layers' of that tree in arrays of length 1, 32, 1024 and so on. I don't think that on average there would be many 'full' nodes since it requires 32 numbers being freed in a row which has small probability.